# How to present 'UIViewController' in Cocoas2D with custom size

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Imagine I have dialog and size of this dialog is 200x200 and I want to present on the iPhone screen temporary (can dismiss with button).

I try it. but the view controller that I presented is replace current scene (dialog and white background border).

I want to present with custom size (200x200) at center of iPhone screen and see my content as background

I try to set dialog's background colour to clearColor and It doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of ViewController you can use UIView

Answer (score 1):

Create your button like this,

```
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonFun) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)ButtonFun {
  UIView *newView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)];
  newView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
  textView.text = @"Write your dialog";
  [textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:15]];
  textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  [newView1 addSubview:textView];

  newView1.center = self.view.center;
  [self.view addSubview:newView1];
}
```

To remove this UIView use UITapGestureRecognizer,or simply

```
[newView1 removeFromSuperview];
```